# check dates for gap of more than one day and group them if continuous in spark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

If I have table with dates in format MM/DD/YYYY like below.

```
+---+-----------+----------+
| id|  startdate|   enddate|
+---+-----------+----------+
|  1| 01/01/2022|01/31/2022|  
|  1| 02/01/2022|02/28/2022|  
|  1| 03/01/2022|03/31/2022|  
|  2| 01/01/2022|03/01/2022|  
|  2| 03/05/2022|03/31/2022| 
|  2| 04/01/2022|04/05/2022|
+---+-----------+----------+
```

How to I group based on id column and if start and end date is continuous?

One thing is if there is more than a one day gap then keep the row on a new line so the above table will become:

```
+---+-----------+----------+
| id|  startdate|   enddate|
+---+-----------+----------+
|  1| 01/01/2022|31/03/2022|  
|  2| 01/01/2022|03/01/2022|  
|  2| 03/05/2022|04/05/2022|  
+---+-----------+----------+
```

id = 1 becomes one row as all dates for id =1 is continuous i.e no gap > 1 but id 2 has two rows as there is a gap between 03/01/2022 and 03/05/2022.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a particular case of the *sessionization* problem (i.e. identify sessions in data based on some conditions).

Here is a possible solution that uses windows.
The logic behind the solution:

1. Associate at each row the temporally previous `enddate` with the same `id`
2. Calculate the difference in days between each `startdate` and the previous `enddate`
3. Identify all the rows that don't have a previous row or is at least two days after the previous row
4. Associate at each row a `session_index`, that is the number of new sessions seen up to this line
5. Aggregate grouping by `id` and `session_index`

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("id")\
          .orderBy("startdate")

df = df \
    .select(
        F.col("id"),
        F.to_date("startdate", "MM/dd/yyyy").alias("startdate"),
        F.to_date("enddate", "MM/dd/yyyy").alias("enddate")
    ) \
    .withColumn("previous_enddate", F.lag('enddate', offset=1).over(w)) \
    .withColumn("date_diff", F.datediff(F.col("startdate"), F.col("previous_enddate"))) \
    .withColumn("is_new_session", F.col("date_diff").isNull() | (F.col("date_diff") > 1)) \
    .withColumn("session_index", F.sum(F.col("is_new_session").cast("int")).over(w))

df.groupBy("id", "session_index") \
    .agg(
        F.min("startdate").alias("startdate"),
        F.max("enddate").alias("enddate")
    ) \
    .drop("session_index")
```